# The correct way to use django for multi table query

Tags: django, orm

```
class Car(models.Model):
    carName = Model.CharField()

class Wheel(models.Model):
    wheelName = Model.CharField()
    car = Model.ForeignKey(Car)

class Equipment(models.Model):
    equipmentName = Model.CharField()
    car = Model.ForeignKey(Car)
```

I want to query all cars having the same name and equipments.
I write the filter like this:

```
Car.objects.filter(wheel__wheelname = 'A', equipment__equipmentname='C')
```

but I got the error
Cannot resolve the keyword "" into field, Choices are: x, xx, xxx

So, is this not supported by django?
BTW, I checked the table, it seems the default table has got a prefix name same as the app name,such as blog_car, how could I disable it in django 1.6.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are querying the `Car` model(table) which has the field `carname`, doesn't have wheel or equipment. That's why you get the error. And I think your model design is wrong. It should be like this:

```
class Wheel(models.Model):
    name = Model.CharField()

class Equipment(models.Model):
    name = Model.CharField()

class Car(models.Model):
    name = Model.CharField()
    wheel = Model.ForeignKey(Wheel)
    equipment = Model.ForeignKey(Equipment)
```

And you shouldn't name fields carName in model Car. Already belongs to car. Whose name could it be? :D

Comment: Oh,I see. So it should like this:   Car.objects.filter(wheel__name=='A', equipment__name=='B')?